# как получить данные из БД в подчинённом представлении (subview, partial view)?

Tags: laravel, blade

Переписываю старый сайт на Laravel. На каждой странице есть общие блоки, которые одинаковы для всех страниц. Например, список всех тегов, который берётся из базы данных. Если я напишу подчинённое представление (не знаю, как точнее перевести subview или partial view) для списка тегов и включу его в общую вёрстку (layout), то где мне написать код, который будет извлекать из БД данные и передавать их в это представление? Кажется, что нужен контроллер для него, но я не понимаю, как он будет вызываться. Обыскал пол-интернета, пока не нашёл ответа.

Подробнее.
Я сделал шаблон для списка тегов `views/shared/all_tags.blade.php`:

```
<div>
...
</div>
```

Я включил его в общий шаблон страниц `views/layouts/app.blade.php`:

```
@include('shared.all_tags')
```

Но в `all_tags.blade.php` мне нужны данные из базы данных. И они нужны только в этом представлении. Поэтому хочется привязать код для их получения только к этому представлению. Не хочется получать их где-то вовне и передавать через второй параметр @include, как советуют в документации Laravel.
Ещё видел способ через view composer. Но это подаётся как средство передать одни и те же данные сразу во многие представления, как я понял. Поэтому мне это кажется не совсем подходящим к моему случаю, когда эти данные нужны только в этом представлении.

Т. е., как я понимаю, мне нужен контроллер (или что-то вроде) для этого представления. Но я не понимаю, кто и как будет его вызывать и надо ли (и как) включать его в маршрутизацию.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо пользоваться именно composer для представления. Вы неверно поняли, что данные которые можно подтянуть композерами для многих представлений. Композеры настраиваются как раз для конкретного представления. Это очевидно из реализации метода compose класса композера. Ну и в провайдере будет указано представление, для которого он отработает. Посмотрите подробнее документацию [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#view-composers)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Значит, буду смотреть. А контроллеров к таким представлениям не бывает? Просто показалась странной такая асимметрия: к представлениям страниц -- контроллеры, а к такому представлению -- что-то специфическое.

Comment: С композером всё получилось.

Comment: "А контроллеров к таким представлениям не бывает?" -  с точки зрения  идеологии фрэймворка не бывает. Но и асимметрии никакой нет. Контроллеры специальные классы, необходимы для обработки входящих запросов к серверу. Один запрос один обработчик, очень условно говоря. Подход с компоновщиками страниц позволит вам не задумываясь переиспользовать выделенную часть на любой странице. Нужно глубже погрузиться в архитектуру фрэймворка [Контроллеры](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers)